# Why is data only being passed to the database on the final iteration?

Tags: java

I am passing data from a select many box in JSF to a mySQL database. When I run the debugger and follow the code through the loop, the code performs as expected. However, only the data in the final iteration of the for loop actually ends up being passed to the database. If anyone can explain why this might be happening it would be appreciated very much!

```
public String addLocation(ArrayList<String> countyList) {
        factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
        EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();   
        em.getTransaction().begin();

        String sessionEmail=Util.getEmail();
        Query myQuery = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM BusinessAccount u WHERE u.email=:email");
        myQuery.setParameter("email", sessionEmail);

        List<BusinessAccount> accounts=myQuery.getResultList();
        BusinessAccount account =accounts.get(0);
        Query myQuery2=em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM County c WHERE c.id=:id");

        for (int i=0; i<countyList.size(); i++){
            String nextCounty=countyList.get(i);
            myQuery2.setParameter("id", Integer.parseInt(nextCounty));

            List<County> myCounties=myQuery2.getResultList();
            String countyFromList=myCounties.get(0).getName();
            locations.setBusinessAccount(account);
            locations.setCountyName(countyFromList);

            account.getLocations().add(locations);
        }   

        em.persist(locations);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();

        return "success";
    }
```

Comment: 1) Why are you creating a `Query` object inside the loop?

Comment: When I create the query object outside the loop and call it inside the loop, I get an error saying "No transaction currently active".

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to your lines:

```
       locations.setBusinessAccount(account);
        locations.setCountyName(countyFromList);
    }
        account.getLocations().add(locations);
        em.persist(locations);
```

**Edit:**
As per my comment: move your
`Query myQuery2=em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM County c WHERE c.id=:id");`
statement just before the
`for` loop 
(after
`BusinessAccount account =accounts.get(0);`
statement)

Think once again what the last 4 lines of code do.
what happens here?

```
locations.setBusinessAccount(account);
locations.setCountyName(countyFromList);
```

`locations` is actually a misleading name for what it is.

and here?

```
account.getLocations().add(locations);
```

and finally what your last statement does?

```
em.persist(locations);
```

Comment: I have edited the code and moved the bracket (had tried that already) but it still doesn't work. If I try to move the commit line inside the for loop as well I have the same problem-only the last iteration is being committed.

Comment: I can't move my query outside the for loop because String nextCounty is the parameter being searched and it is being incremented on each iteration of i.

Comment: You don't have to create new query on every iteration of your loop, you can just set new parameter value `myQuery2.setParameter("id", Integer.parseInt(nextCounty));` inside the loop

Comment: Thanks for your help- I appreciate it. I understand what you are saying about creating the new query and have changed it (edited above). However I don't see what the problem with the last 4 lines of the code is (although there obviously is a problem somewhere). In this code, I assign the account to the locations object and then set a CountyName. I then add the locations to the to the arrayList of accounts. I then persist this to the database. Can you explain in a bit more detail what you see as the problem because I don't see it. Thanks again-your help is appreciated very much!

Comment: That was the reason why I mentioned that your variable name `locations` is misleading (for you). It is **not** `locations` (plural) it should be `location` (singular). This way you will see what you are actually `persist`ing is **not** what you need to `persist`

Comment: As it stands now when your `persist` statement is inside the loop you update a single record number of times, when it is outside the loop you save it once.

Comment: I understand your point but if you look at the updated code above, I have placed the persist outside the for loop as you suggest and I'm still getting the same issue, with only the last value of the iteration being persisted. thanks

Comment: i really don't know what I'm doing wrong here. Can you tell me what the right way to do it is so that I can learn from it. I've tried so many different things and I can't get it to work. thanks for your help-im new to programming and am trying to figure a lot of new concepts out here!

Comment: What are you adding your locations to?  Do you update it? I don't see where you do it, so I must assume that you don't. As far as I can see you **update** location(s) either inside the loop or after the loop. Both will have the same effect as you use the same location object.